# Prevent greybox from closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't really know how to describe my problem, but on the project im currently working an employee can add a timerule. This timerule is being filled out in a greybox iframe popup that links to a new page.

If someone clicks outside the greybox, the greybox dissapears and the old page (where the button 'add timerule' is located) re-appeares. The problem is that some employees sometimes accidently click outside the popup and therefore lose their data.

My assignment is to prevent the popup from closing when someone clicks outside of the greybox (like, clicking on the grey area around it, that would normally close it).

I've tried using the jQuery focusout method on the div that was created, but that doesnt seem to work for iframes.

Any advice?

The button that gives the greybox/popupbox:

```
<input type="button" name="todo_invoeren" value="Tijdregel" style="width: 100px;" onclick="return GB_showCenter('Toevoegen tijdregel aan melding 269596', '../../../hoofdmenu/modules/todos/index.php?meld_id=269596&onsite=1', 350, 1150);" '="">
```

If you click that, you get send to a new page which will use the $_GET that was added. Inside the greybox is just an additional form placed in a div which the employee should fill out. I don't really know what i should add regarding implementation.

Comment: We'll definitely need more info to be able to help you. Mainly implementation details

Comment: I wouldn't really know what i should add further.

Comment: I'm sure there's an overlay on the page below your popup which is usually only one element (div). The easiest way is to listen for click events on that and decide if you want to close the popup or not.